# conditional formatting of a cell with text value from two different cells and limits to entered figure

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I came across an issue that is beyond my capability with conditional formatting.

Here, I am entering a figure in a cell, say B11 using multiple conditions in cells F5 (Kings and Queens) and B7 (Low, Medium and High).

I want to enter a figure in this cell (B11) between 90 and 20 which are grades.

When I enter the number, say 98, it must return 90 and 20 when I enter any figure below 20 such as 17 when F5=Queens and B7=High but when I enter 77, it returns 77.

If I change to F5=Queens and B7= Medium, I want to enter a figure in this cell between 60 and 15.

If I enter 12, it must return 15 and if 65, must enter 60 in B11 but if I enter 48, it retains 48.

Lastly, if F5=Kings and B7= Low, Medium or High in B11, it must enter 20 no matter the figure I enter in B11.

I want to use a single formula but it has been very difficult because my knowledge on Excel is a bit low on that.

How can I achieve this?

I have Excel 2010.

Comment: Thanks for the editing. It will make for easier reading.

Comment: I can't follow your description. A screen cap of current data and expected result can be worth a thousand words. You can upload some at http://imgur.com and link to them.

Comment: What's the range for each conditional formatting? It still not very clearly.

Comment: I worked on this question manually using a cell C10 different from the cell I want to conditionally format (B11) to enter my figures with the following formula and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

With this formula which I entered in cell B11, I was able to get an answer. The only problem is that I used a separate cell C10 to enter my figures instead of B11. If someone can use this information to conditionally format B11, I will be grateful. =IF(AND($F5="QUEENS",$B7="HIGH",$C10<=20),"20",IF(AND($F5="QUEENS",$B7="HIGH",$C10>90),"90",IF(AND($F5="QUEENS",$B7="MEDIUM",$C10<15),"15",IF(AND($F5="QUEENS",$B7="MEDIUM",$C10>60),"60",IF(AND($E5="QUEENS",$B7="LOW"),"5",IF(AND($F5="KINGS",OR($B7="HIGH",$B7="MEDIUM",$B7="LOW")),"20",$C10)))))). Thank you.